# Why need the author to add the keyword remember in this @Composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the project ThemingCodelab, you can see full code [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/ThemingCodelab/app/src/main/java/com/codelab/theming/ui/start/Home.kt).

I think that the keyword `remember` is not necessary in Code A.

I have tested the Code B, it seems that I can get the same result just like Code A.

Why need the author to add the keyword `remember` in this `@Composable` ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun Home() {
    val featured = remember { PostRepo.getFeaturedPost() }
    val posts = remember { PostRepo.getPosts() }
    MaterialTheme {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = { AppBar() }
        ) { innerPadding ->
            LazyColumn(contentPadding = innerPadding) {
                item {
                    Header(stringResource(R.string.top))
                }
                item {
                    FeaturedPost(
                        post = featured,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                    )
                }
                item {
                    Header(stringResource(R.string.popular))
                }
                items(posts) { post ->
                    PostItem(post = post)
                    Divider(startIndent = 72.dp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun Home() {
    val featured =PostRepo.getFeaturedPost() 
    val posts =  PostRepo.getPosts() 
    ...//It's the same with the above code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `remember` to prevent recomputation during recomposition.

Your example works without `remember` because this view will not recompose while you scroll through it.

But if you use animations, add state variables or use a view model, your view can be recomposed many times(when animating up to once a frame), in which case getting data from the repository will be repeated many times, so you need to use `remember` to save the result of the computation between recompositions.

So always use `remember` inside a view builder if the calculations are at least a little heavy, even if right now it looks like the view is not gonna be recomposed.

You can read more about the state in compose in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI), which explains the basic principles.